# Indirect source quotations

Tags: citations, quotes, mla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing speech and interviews in biographies](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/citing-speech-and-interviews-in-biographies)

How do you quote an indirect source (source quoted in another source) when there are explanatory words within the indirect source and before it?  Specifically in MLA style?

Comment: @JohnSmithers - The question you point to doesn't specify MLA. but within it, [this answer](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/3611/26) addresses this in MLA style. I'm closing this and I'll tag the older question with [tag:mla].

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you state the original author of the quotation. Then, you explicitly cite the source from where you took that quotation. For exemple:

[...] Cohn has demonstrated X, as stated in (Author that cite Cohn) [...]